# Solid State Relay and Arduino Nano Power Failure Solution

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, solid-state-relay, schottky, backup

This is my first time, and I'm looking for guidance on my approach to a particular problem: ensuring that a Solid State Relay (SSR) closes whenever my Arduino Nano loses power. The SSR, powered by the Arduino Nano's 5V pin, is designed to activate a bulb either during specific trigger events (as programmed in the Arduino) or when the AC-DC adapter, powering Arduino Nano, wall socket loses power.

To maintain power to the SSR in the event of an Arduino power failure, I have set up a backup system using 3 AA batteries. The challenge is to create a circuit that switches to battery power only when the Arduino is unable to supply power. My current design utilizes 2 Schottky diodes. However, to prevent current leakage (which is dangerous to non-rechargeable AA batteries), I have used a P-channel MOSFET to block reverse current flow.

Here is the circuit diagram for reference:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I am seeking assistance with the following:

1. Confirmation that this circuit effectively prevents backflow current when the Arduino's power supply is active.
2. Assurance that the battery will not drain while the Arduino's power source is dominant.
3. Verification that the circuit switches to the battery source within an acceptable delay (less than 0.5 seconds) when the Arduino loses power.
   4.Guidance on connecting the SSR (which is low trigger so needs to be grounded to activate) to one of the digital pins on the Arduino Nano, especially considering the common ground shared when the battery source is used.

I apologize for the following:

- The circuit diagram is not complete; additional resistors are needed
  to prevent short-circuiting. The image is meant to convey the basic
  principle rather than a detailed schematic.
- The relay channel pin control circuit is not connected, as I am uncertain about this
  aspect.
- I have used the symbol for a Zener diode instead of a
  Schottky diode, and the SSR symbol is not accurate due to limitations
  in the diagramming tool I used.
- Instead of a traditional schematic, I
  have provided an image for ease of creation.
- I have posted this query
  on multiple platforms to reach a broader audience and gather diverse
  insights.

I greatly appreciate any help or advice on this project.

For request from comment, here is the datasheet of OMRON G3MB-202P (1565E) that is used in SSR module that I purchased:

https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Omron%20PDFs/G3MB.pdf

The module that I'm using reverse the polarity to make the SSR low triggered. Here is the link to product page:

https://robu.in/product/a03b-1-road-5v-low-level-solid-state-relay-module-with-fuse-ssr-250v-2a-fuse/

Utilising @RoyC solution I developed new circuit:

[image: Circuit Diagram 2]

Is this circuit solves all of problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a datasheet for the SSR. Please edit it into the question.

Comment: The online store from where I bought didn't link the datasheet. Here is the [link](https://robu.in/product/a03b-1-road-5v-low-level-solid-state-relay-module-with-fuse-ssr-250v-2a-fuse/) to SSR. The module is using OMRON G3MB-202P (1565E). So should I search its datasheet?

Comment: Yes, you should not rely on the stores specifications.

Comment: @RoyC I've added the datasheet